# Integrate C++ .dll wrapped by SWIG to C# project

Tags: c#, c++-cli, swig

I have 2 solutions under VS2019: *RLibrary* (contains C++ project) and *VTApp* (contains C# project).

Solution *RLibrary* has two projects: *RLib* C++ .dll and *SwigW* (wrapper project).
*SwigW* generated the following files: *RLibCSHARP_wrap.cxx*, *RLib.cs*, *RLib.i* and *RLibPINVOKE.cs*.

In the *RLibPINVOKE.cs* I have lines like:

```
   class RLibPINVOKE {
    //...
     static RLibPINVOKE() {
    }
          [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("SwigW", EntryPoint="CSharp_new_Create")]
          public static extern global::System.IntPtr new_Create();
          [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("SwigW", EntryPoint="CSharp_new_Request")]
          public static extern global::System.IntPtr new_Request();
          // ...
    }
```

So, after building *RLibrary* solution I will have two .dll (also .lib) files: *RLib.dll* and *SwigW.dll*.
I want to use `new_Create()`, `new_Request()` functions from the *VTApp*.
*VTApp* has two projects as well: *UI* and *Core*. *UI* has a reference to *Core*. I added *RLibPINVOKE.cs* file to the *Core* project by just *Right Click->Add->Existing item* and tried to use above mentioned functions from the *UI* project within **namespace UI**, i.e.,

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace UI {

public partial class MainWindow {

private void Execute_Req(object sender, EREventArgs e)
{
   //...
   IntPtr p = new_Create();
}

}
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting *CS01013: The name 'new_Create' does not exist in the current context.* error.
In my opinion, even without adding *SwigW.dll* to the *Core* project I shouldn't have had this kind of compile time error. So, what is the problem here? How can I add *SwigW.dll* into the *Core* project properly if I need to add it? Also, should I add *RLib.dll* to the *Core* as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `RLibPINVOKE.new_Create()`. The method is inside a `class RLibPINVOKE`

```
class RLibPINVOKE {
//...
```

You'll perhaps need a `using`, but the Visual Studio should be able to suggest it to you on the `RLibPINVOKE`.

Comment: Now compiler complains: "CS0122: 'RLibPINVOKE' is inaccessible due to its protection level. Also, should I only add RLibPINVOKE.cs in the *Core* project or .cxx is also needed?

Comment: OK, I added 'public' keyword before 'class' and it worked. By default it seems it is private.